# Can we apply Formica directly to bare drywall?

Tags: drywall, adhesive

Can [Formica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formica_(plastic)) be applied directly to bare drywall? If it can, which adhesive is best to use?  We want to apply it to the walls around a toilet in an unfinished basement setting.

Comment: I don't know why you couldn't. But note that you can often get wall panelling with waterproof designs already applied.

Comment: I don't know if you can or cannot, but I don't recommend it.  When it comes time to remove, having something even primer will allow the paneling to be removed without as much damage to the drywall.

Comment: This is in a small corner area of the basement, which is unfinished with concrete floors. It is a rental, so would be easier to clean, and if we needed to remove it in the future it will be a simple removal.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can.  It will be a better water deterrent than painted drywall and will certainly be easier to maintain and clean.

Is it recommended?  Probably not.  But not everything *has* to be approved.

I would adhere Formica with the same mastic for applying vinyl tile.  It is easy to apply and work, and has more than adequate adhesion.

Comment: That is our exact concern:  easy to clean ~ this is in a rental house.  It is only a small corner area so it seemed reasonable to us.  If we have to remove it in the future it won't be a big expensive removal job.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Know that drywall has a chalky core and is clad both sides with paper. Once you adhere anything to drywall you are adhereing it to paper. If there is a shift in ambient humidity there is a chance the material will buckle and rip the paper away from the drywall core. A professional would remove the drywall and adhere the Formica to a substrate like particleboard and install the panels.